# Enter data into input field not working with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm making basic script for sing-in into Instagram.
I faced with this error

[image]

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')

username = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('login')
```

Comment: so the error is it can't locate the browser?

Comment: @becixb it open the browser and going to url, but it stops when need to enter login to input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
time.sleep(5)
```

before

```
username = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('login')
```

Might be page not fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

The error reads 'Window not found. The browser window may have been closed'. It happened in line browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body"). The Instagram login page has two such elements, and you need only one of them. You should make the query more specific, for instance by making it return only the first element with the tag.